# ModernUIのModernTab.Linksでリンク先のページに情報を渡したい。

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

WPFアプリでModern UI　[リンクの説明をここに入力](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui)
を使っています。
ここでModernTab.Linksを使ってタブを選択すると表示する画面を切り替えています。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```html
<UserControl x:Class="FirstFloor.ModernUI.App.Content.LoremIpsumList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
             xmlns:app="clr-namespace:FirstFloor.ModernUI.App"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <mui:ModernTab SelectedSource="/2" Layout="List">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 1" Source="/1" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 2" Source="/2" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 3" Source="/3"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 4" Source="/4" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Lorem Ipsum 5" Source="/5"/>
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
            
            <!-- ensures new LoremIpsum content is loaded for each uri -->
            <mui:ModernTab.ContentLoader>
                <app:LoremIpsumLoader />
            </mui:ModernTab.ContentLoader>
        </mui:ModernTab>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**ここから質問なのですが、各LinksのSourceで指定したxamlを表示するときにxamlへデータを渡したいです。**
例えばタブ名をやタブのIndex,タブのもつプロパティ値を右画面に表示されるxamlに表示させるようなイメージです。
依存関係プロパティを使うのか、他のもっとよい方法があるのかご教授ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern UI for WPFが規定で用意しているフレームワークとクラスをそのまま利用する場合、最もシンプルなのはSource属性に指定するUriに対してquery文字列を追加するアプローチになるかと思います。
例えば、Twitterクライアントの各タイムラインをタブで実装して、同じTimeline.xamlで表示し、パラメーターとして表示対象を渡したい場合、

```
<mui:ModernTab.Links>
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Timeline" Source="/Timeline.xaml?mode=timeline" />
    <mui:Link DisplayName="Mention" Source="/Tineline.xaml?mode=mention" />
    <mui:Link DisplayName="DM" Source="/Timeline.xaml?mode=dm&display=popup"/>
</mui:ModernTab.Links>
```

などと記述しておき、Timeline.xaml側ではIContentのOnNavigateToメソッドを実装してNavigationEventArgsのSourceプロパティをUriとして解読します。
Uriクラスの各種プロパティが相対Uriには利用できないので正規表現でざっくり実装ですが、こんな感じで。

```
public partial class Timeline : UserControl, IContent
{
    public void OnFragmentNavigation(FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.FragmentNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var display = Regex.Match(e.Source.OriginalString, "[?&]+display=(?<display>[^&]+)").Groups["display"].Value;
        var mode = Regex.Match(e.Source.OriginalString, "[?&]+mode=(?<mode>[^&]+)").Groups["mode"].Value;
    }

    public void OnNavigatingFrom(FirstFloor.ModernUI.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Modern UI for WPFの既定のLinkクラスが本当に最低限なので、そのまま利用する一番素直なやり方としてはこんな感じになるか、と思います。
文字列渡しになるので高度な受け渡しはできませんし、URL Encodingに注意する必要があります。
あとは力づくでごりごりと継承するなり、ハッシュ値でも渡してみるなりやり方は色々か、と。

Comment: とても参考になりました｡ IContentを使えばURIで文字列渡しができますね｡　渡したい値がクラスのインスタンスだったりすると難しいのですね｡‌​　ありがとうございます